# UIPicker within UIScrollView - Ignore drags/moves but capture touches

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uicontrol

I have a rather large (in screen-estate) UIControl that I'm putting into a UIScrollView. Being a UIControl, it hijacks all touches and any drag that starts from within the control will not be reflected by the UIScrollView.

This control only needs UIControlEventTouchUpInside, so is there any way to "only" listen to that event?

My first instinct was to override hitTest:withEvent: and return the superview if it detected a drag, but that doesn't provide any information on the *type* of control event.

My last resort is to make it a generic UIView, but I'd rather not go down that road if possible.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, for clarity, I purposefully set delaysContentTouches to NO to support other features on the screen I am working on. The unintended side effects result in Joel H's second point.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting both the `canCancelContentTouches` and `delaysContentTouches` properties of your UIScrollView to YES.

When the UIScrollView property `canCancelContentTouches` is set to YES, it should transfer any scrolling/drag touches to the scroll view and cancel whatever that touch would have been registered in the subview.

The scroll view's `delaysContentTouches` should be set to YES as well. This will prevent drags from being triggered as taps (because the handler fires off too soon).

[UIScrollView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry I don't have a better answer for you!